# Is it possible to background job social shares on iOS?

Tags: ios, twitter, facebook-ios-sdk

My app will most likely be used when no internet connection is available but I'd still like the user to be able to share content when they're using it - and then have my app post to FB/Twitter/etc when they have internet access.

Can I make an FB or Twitter API call in the background that posts the update after the user has selected to do so previously (ie. when theres no data available) ?

Answer (score 2):

Not with `SLComposeViewController`.

You can present UI that's similar to it and that captures the share data and then later, when the user has internet access, you could use FB's and Twitter's APIs to do the share.

[Here's how to do it for Facebook](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/eric-stroh/ios-6-turorial-integrating-facebook-your-applications), the Advanced integration section.

Twitter is somewhat similar.